# Como repito a execução de um código em python?

Tags: python, automatização, pyautogui

Criei uma automação em Python através do PyAutoGUI para votar no BBB. Gostaria de saber como deixo ele em loop para que ele finalize e inicie novamente.

```
import pyautogui  
import time  
import itertools

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.5  
pyautogui.press('winleft')  
pyautogui.write('chrome')  
pyautogui.press('enter')  
time.sleep(1)  
pyautogui.write('https://gshow.globo.com/realities/bbb/bbb22/votacao/paredao-bbb22-vote-para-eliminar-arthur-aguiar-douglas-silva-eliezer-ou-jessilane-ab6c950c-77a6-4109-82a1-806c41bb0290.ghtml')  
pyautogui.press('enter')  
time.sleep(6)  
pyautogui.press(['down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'down'])  
pyautogui.click(1955,640)  
time.sleep(5)  
pyautogui.click(1925,360)
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Coloca seu codigo dentro de um 

while True: código

Comment: como? coloco todo o código dentro do while?

Comment: Poder ser no for,  que repita 1 a 30 ou 1 a 1000.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
While True:
    #insira o código que realiza a votação aqui
```

Assim o código ficará executando até que vc pare o script

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Com a ajuda dos colegas, consegui repetir a execução do código com o laço while True. Ficou da seguinte forma:

```py
import pyautogui
import sys, time, msvcrt, random, time, os

while True:
    def abrir_navegador():
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
        pyautogui.press('winleft')
        pyautogui.write('chrome')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.write('https://gshow.globo.com/realities/bbb/bbb22/votacao/paredao-bbb22-vote-para-eliminar-eliezer-gustavo-ou-paulo-andre-d266c563-e34e-499c-92a9-7ca39992e197.ghtml')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(3)

    def votacao_bbb():
        pyautogui.click(1989,593)
        time.sleep(3)
        pyautogui.click(1913,640)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.click(2050, 375)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'f4')
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 2

    print(abrir_navegador())
    print(votacao_bbb())
```

Answer (score -2):

você poderia colocar uma variável como "True", então, definir o while para "enquanto variável for "True" repetir o código e ao fim dele, adicionar a função sleep. Entretanto, talvez seja melhor você usar o sistema operacional para cuidar disso. Faça o código em Python, e use o sistema operacional (Linux: cronjob /Windows: Agendador de Tarefas) para controlar de quanto em quanto tempo aquele script deve rodar.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).